# jQuery generalizing dynamic selector input

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, jquery-selectors

I am in a situation where I need to use dynamic ID's of the format `functionalDescription_IDNUMBER` throughout my page and I need to target certain areas based on what the `IDNUMBER` was for the object that was clicked.  However, I am not sure how to generalize the function so that I don't have to generate this same code for every unique ID (for instance, it could end in ABC, DEF, XYZ, asfSa1s3d6fZ, etc).

Example:

jQuery function that I would like to generalize (where XYZ is the dynamically generated ID Number in this case)...

```
$("#videoThumbnail_XYZ").click(function() {
    $("#thumbnailDescription_XYZ").fadeOut(300, function() {
        $("#videoPlayer_XYZ").fadeIn(100);
    });
});
```

For a given piece of HTML:

```
<div id="videoPlayer_XYZ" class="videoPlayer">
    <iframe title="Video Player" type="text/html" width="638" height="390" src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="thumbnailDescription_XYZ" class="thumbnailDescription">
    <div id="videoThumbnail_XYZ" class="videoThumbnail left">
        <img src="images/videoThumbnail.png" />
    </div>
    <!-- more code in here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) `^=`

```
$("[id^='videoThumbnail']").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
    $("#thumbnailDescription_" + id).fadeOut(300, function() {
        $("#videoPlayer_" + id).fadeIn(100);
    });
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/m67Y7/1/

---

or using the same `split()` logic, attach the event to the `videoThumbnail` class

```
$(".videoThumbnail").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
    $("#thumbnailDescription_" + id).fadeOut(300, function() {
        $("#videoPlayer_" + id).fadeIn(100);
    });
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/m67Y7/

Comment: Thanks hunter!  That gives me a few more topics to read up on as well

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could do this is container based. Then all the selectors would be based on class with a live selector within `<div data-videoid="XYZ">` instead of global unique id.

```
<div data-videoid="XYZ"> <!-- unique id is stored at parent level -->
    <div class="videoPlayer">
        <iframe title="Video Player" type="text/html" width="638" height="390" src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnailDescription">
        <div class="videoThumbnail left">
            <img src="images/videoThumbnail.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery templates](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquerytemplate) are a good way of templating markup with minor variations.  Also, check out this [jquery random](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/random) string generator.